# android load tab icon from internal memory

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I need to change tab icon if selected or not. I am using following selector that works if I use images from drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/search_selected"
        android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/search_normal" />
</selector>
```

However, I need to use images from data/data... and use following code to load image from there. How to handle selector in order to load proper image (when selected or not) if I need to load it from internal memory? Thank you

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);

File imgFile = new  File(pathImage);

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    icon.setImageBitmap(myBitmap); }

    //icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab_search;
```

Comment: So you have both selected and un_selected image in your external memory. right?

Comment: right! both images are on created folder on data/data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StateListDrawables`.

Get your both images as `BitmapDrawable` and do something like this:

```
StateListDrawable selector = new StateListDrawable();
selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_enabled }, yourDefaultBitmapDrawable);
selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_selected }, yourSelectedBitmapDrawable);
icon.setImageDrawable(selector);
```

Comment: mm sounds like that is what I need! however, is giving me an error on: selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_enabled }, myBitmap); suggests that change type of "myBitmap" to "Drawable".

Comment: Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(myBitmap); solved it! I really appreciate your help, thanks